# Trying to enter a pos but need a password

Tags: eve-online

I bounced off of the force field, Where do I put in the password for star base or pos?

Answer (score 6):

Right click on your ship and select `Enter POS Password`

Comment: I am such a noob

Comment: @Duke did you not manage to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the menu to enter the forcefield password two ways.

1: Click on your ship in space and select the 'enter POS password' option
2: Click on the HUD and select the same thing.

Please keep in mind that you can only have one stored POS password at a time. Also if you are inside a pos and the password is changed you will be ejected at a high rate of speed. (This is one tactic used to escape when you have a fleet trapped in a pos)